# Force RestClient to pass string without converting

Tags: ruby, json, rest-client

I have a ReST call that carries a payload:

```
{
    "definitionId": <nnnn>,
    "stringVars": 
        {
            "pData":"{\"project\": \"x49383\", \"section\": \"<section>\", \"brand\": \"<brand>\"}"
        }
}
```

When I POST it via RestClient, I can't prevent the string value to pData from being converted into JSON, but the server is expecting a string. I tried enclosing it in a literal:

```
"pData":%Q{{\"project\": \"x49383\", \"section\": \"<section>\", \"brand\": \"<brand>\"}}
```

I also tried passing the whole thing as a string and pre-converting it with JSON.parse().

But this didn't work.

Complicating this is that fact that I need string interpolation in the pData value.

Comment: What is the `Content-Type` of your `POST` request? Try using `text/plain`, if you're not already.

Comment: Hi Tom.

I can't really change the Content-Type as it's a proprietary format required by the service.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. What do you mean by "I can't prevent the string value to pData from being converted into JSON"? It looks like it's already JSON. What do you want the  actual POST body to look like, and what does it look like instead?

Comment: To reiterate, could you display the actual (debug) HTTP request data? It sounds like there's a lot of confusion between content types and data formats; one or both of your systems are behaving weirdly.